# Access server's web browser from local machine

Tags: server, browser

I can able to access the folder views from server machine using **nautilus**. Now i want to access the **apache tomcat** to access the browser view from that server. So please help in how to access the server's browser view.

Comment: Have you tried typing `localhost` at your browser's address bar? It will work unless the default port is other than `80`, if you need help detecting the port I'll be glad to assist.

Comment: Would [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1005087/653515) answer be of any help? It basically describes how to set up a dynamic tunnel.

Comment: Thanks @vidarlo I will try the link and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access tomcat, you can connect to the machine using your browser. This depends on what services you have installed with tomcat, as they can set the port they advertise on, but generally 8080 is a good start:

http://:8080

However, I was wondering about the "from a server". If you have ssh'd into the server, you are in command line mode, and you can't run a web browser from there (well, you can use curl or wget).

Comment: From curl or wget i can able to run the web browser locally? Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. curl will send an HTTP request to your tomcat server, and it can print the returned results. Use jq to format json.  But its not a web browser.